# How to make link back to parent post on WordPress media attachment page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Related to [Redirect Wordpress Media attachment page to root location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064742/redirect-wordpress-media-attachment-page-to-root-location), [Wordpress get Post infomation from attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224274/wordpress-get-post-infomation-from-attachment), and [How to Redirect WordPress Attachment Page to Original Post or Page](https://themeisle.com/blog/redirect-wordpress-attachment-pages/):

On WordPress attachment pages there are links generated with styles nav_prev and nav_next (in RDG Forest theme at least). How do I get a central link in the same row as them, linking users back to the parent post the image is attached to?

What if an image is attached to multiple posts? How does the 'return' link know where to go?

---

### My attempt so far:

First add a CSS style for that 'return to parent post' link, mimicking .nav-next style.

```
.nav-center {
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.142857143rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.142857143rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Then go to image.php and edit the spans for the prev and next nav items. For example look for:

```
    <nav id="image-navigation" class="navigation" role="navigation">
        <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_image_link(false, __('&larr; Previous Image', 'rcg-forest')); ?></span>
        <span class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link(false, __('Next Image &rarr;', 'rcg-forest')); ?></span>
    </nav>
```

I want to use the following function to get the parent post URL, but I haven't figured out how to link a span class text using this function.

```
get_permalink($post->post_parent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, with some CSS revision needed, using a more elaborate attempt.

**Pseudocode:** If there is a parent post, echo a link to a post at the root blog URL, then print the post_parent in that link, as a nav button to return to the parent post.

```
        <nav id="image-navigation" class="navigation" role="navigation">
            <span class="nav-previous"><?php prev_image_link(false, __('&larr; Previous Image', 'rcg-forest')); ?></span>
            <?php if ( is_attachment() && isset($post->post_parent) && is_numeric($post->post_parent) && ($post->post_parent != 0) ) :
                echo '<span class="nav-center"><a href="';
                echo get_post($id)->post_parent;
                echo '">&rarr; Return to Parent Post &larr;</a></span>';
            endif; ?>
            <span class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link(false, __('Next Image &rarr;', 'rcg-forest')); ?></span>
        </nav>
```

Also, CSS needed modification so all 3 nav items would show on one line. Playing with width %s, this worked for me:

```
.nav-previous {
    float: left;
    width: 36%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.142857143rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-center {
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.142857143rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 40%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.142857143rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```